# name_servers= from resolvconf.conf are not prepended, they're used alone

Tags: networkmanager, dnsmasq, resolvconf

I enabled `rc-manager=resolvconf` in `NetworkManager.conf` and now resolvconf is used to maintain resolv.conf. Currently, I have just one wired connection and my dhcp server returns 2 search domains and 4 name servers and with the default resolvconf configuration they are all added to `resolv.conf`.

I have a standalone `dnsmasq` and according to `RESOLVCONF.CONF(5)`:

> ```
>  name_servers
>          Prepend name servers to the dynamically generated list.  You should 
>          set this to 127.0.0.1 if you use a local name server other than libc.
> ```

So I uncommented `name_servers=127.0.0.1` in `resolvconf.conf`, but now, when I enable the connection in NetworkManager only the search domains are updated in `resolv.conf` in accordance with DHCP settings. As for the name servers, just a single line is always present in the file:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Why doesn't `resolvconf` append the four other name servers to it?

This is the captured args and stdin from NetworkManager:

```
/usr/bin/resolvconf -a NetworkManager <<'EOF'
# Generated by NetworkManager
search domain1.com,domain2.com reallin.basin
nameserver 10.14.33.139
nameserver 10.14.33.140
nameserver 192.168.149.11
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 192.168.110.11
EOF
```

Actually, I didn't want to enable `resolvconf`. All I wanted was to prepend 127.0.0.1 to the name servers added from DHCP by NetworkManager, but I couldn't figure out how to do this with `rc-manager=symlink` which is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work I had to add the other setting:

```
resolv_conf_local_only=NO
```

Surprisingly, it is YES by default.